# How to get XML response string along with Kotlin Data Model in android?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, xml-parsing, retrofit2

I am parsing XML response using SimpleXmlConverterFactory which works perfect but it gives me data model classes with respect to provided model class while making API call but now I need a response string as well which I got from the server.

I have tried by taking responseBody in the model class but due to that it gives error in my XML parsing

```
class ResponseAndPojo(val value : MODEL, val response : ResponseBody)
```

Using the above class I am trying to parse response with a retrofit API call but it is not working

Comment: yes but i need actual XML data

Comment: Then in your request received the response as `ResponseBody` and then convert it to your Model. You can't do whatever you want in your way

Comment: how to convert response body to the model as respone is of XML and i am not sure that Gson will help here!!

Comment: You have to use your parser to convert it MODEL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved this by using SimpleXmlConverterFactory below is my code which will use XML response body and convert it to data model class so that I got both XML response string and model class

```
val strategy = AnnotationStrategy()
val serializer = Persister(strategy)
val model = SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create(serializer).responseBodyConverter(CustomModel::class.java,arrayOfNulls<Annotation>(0),null)?.convert(response) as CustomModel
```